# Fixed headers for multiple gridviews using one scrollbar (slider)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have four asp.net gridviews on one page. I use Jquery slider to scroll all of them at same time (only vertical). **How can I freeze header rows while scrolling ?**

All my grids are inside an updatepanel.

Each gridview are inside Div. Here is example of the style for the div:

```
<div id="grid1Div" style="overflow-y:hidden;" class="gridHeight">

.gridHeight
{
    height:430px;
}
```

Here is example for grid style (all are styled almost similar)

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" CssClass="exGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCreated="grid1_RowCreated" meta:resourcekey="grid1Resource1"  >

.exGrid1 { 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #DDE8EE; 
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
    border: solid 1px #FFFFFF; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    color: #666666;
}
.exGrid1 td { 
    padding: 2px; 
    border: solid 1px #FFFFFF; 
    color: #666666/*#000000*/; 
    font-size: 0.8em; 
}
.exGrid1 th { 
    padding: 4px 2px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    background: #76B7E2 url(grd_head.png) repeat-x top; 
    border-left: solid 1px #FFFFFF; 
    font-size: 0.8em; 
}
.exGrid1 .alt { background: #fcfcfc url(grd_alt.png) repeat-x top; }
.exGrid1 .pgr { background: #424242 url(grd_pgr.png) repeat-x top; }
.exGrid1 .pgr table { margin: 5px 0; }
.exGrid1 .pgr td { 
    border-width: 0; 
    padding: 0 6px; 
    border-left: solid 1px #666; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    line-height: 12px; 
 }   
.exGrid1 .pgr a { color: #666; text-decoration: none; }
.exGrid1 .pgr a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
```

And here are the Jquery part where I set the scroll heights for all grids.

```
function setGridScroll() {
    var scrollPane = $('#divScroll');
    var scrollGrid1 = $('#grid1');
    var scrollGrid2 = $('#grid2');
    var scrollGrid3 = $('#grid3');
    var scrollGrid4 = $('#grid4');

    var scrollMaxHei = $('#grid1')[0].scrollHeight - 230;
    scrollPane.slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        value: scrollMaxHei-200,
        min: 200,
        max: scrollMaxHei,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var setValue = scrollMaxHei - ui.value-200;
            scrollGrid1.scrollTop(setValue);
            scrollGrid3.scrollTop(setValue);
            scrollGrid4.scrollTop(setValue);
            scrollGrid2.scrollTop(setValue);

        }
    });
}
```

Can I freeze header just by setting something to my fixedheader class on gridview(s)?

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="fixedHeader" />


.fixedHeader
    {
     position: relative;
    }
```

Is there a easier way to do this?. I need to keep all gridviews separate and cannot use scrollbars for all of them. Also the scrollbar needs to be at right on its own div because users can Hide gridviews if they want.

Comment: Are the grids side-by-side or arranged vertically?

Comment: Grids are horizontally side by side.